# Show "For best results, Please enable Javascript"

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to enabled a banner in my opencart shop.

The site is PHP, i basically just need a banner at the top of the page to alert users that don't have JS turned on to turn it on.

i used

```
   <noscript>
   <div id="noscript-warning">We reccomend using javascript for the best viewing pleasure ></div>
   </noscript>
```

However this does not seem to be executing.

Comment: ...and you're testing it with JavaScript turned off, right?

Comment: @David maybe it doesn't like your spelling of "recommend". :-)

Comment: Try replacing the `<noscript>` tags with `<div>` tags, and see if it's displaying then. If it's still not being shown, then perhaps it's being hidden by some other part of the layout.

Comment: Along the lines of what @AndreiBârsan said, try removing the <div> tags to make sure there's no weird CSS or something hiding that <div> inside the <noscript>

Comment: Thanks For all the comments :) Please excuse my spelling error. I did check with JS disabled. Still no luck. I then removed the <noscript> and replaced with <div>. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not getting feedback from comments, so I'll post possible issues.

- You're testing with JavaScript enabled
- Your CSS styling of the element is hiding the message
- Your CSS styling of other elements is hiding the message
- You've posted a modified example that doesn't reflect the actual code
- Your trailing `>` is breaking the layout in whatever browser you're using to test *(not likely)*
- You're attempting to generate the no-script element using JavaScript `:P`

Comment: :) Thanks for the suggestions am not i am, however, this does not seem to be the case. I have tested across multiple browsers with no luck.

Comment: @DavidMurray: *What* isn't the case? If you're testing across multiple browsers, and none give the desired result, then clearly there's something wrong in your code, or in your testing. I'm just offering possibilities since you've provided little to work from in your question.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort am not i am. I reviewed my code and noticed that i was working within an inactive template file. Thanks you for your time:)

Answer (score 0):

The `<noscript>` tag is anecdotally deprecated (http://www.html-5.com/changes/noscript-tag.html), though I doubt that's the problem.

In any case, you can just create a script that removes a "You need Javascript enabled" div.

```
<div id="jserror">Enable Javascript Please!</div>
<script>

        document.getElementById("jserror").style.display = "none";

</script>
```

Edit: an `eventListener` isn't even required.